# How are Web API access tokens validated on the server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, access-token

Once a `WebAPI` access token is generated, how does `WebAPI` validate that token for the next request? I wonder if I can use an `[Authorize]` attribute, it must compare the token sent by the client with the token at the server side, if stored somewhere. Does it just check if token is present and not its value?

Comment: You are talking about access tokens and then about cookies. You need to clarify what is your environment. Are you using bearer token authentication in OWIN? Please add any code related to authentication so we can help you.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma Yes, I'm using OWIN. Just want to know more about tokens. My question is straight forward.

Comment: Have you looked at [Secure a Web API with Individual Accounts and Local Login in ASP.NET Web API 2.2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api)?

Comment: From the link @Igor provided, I think you will read another link [OWIN OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The secret key is transmitted in the *header* of the request from the client to the server, and the contents are validated at the server at each request where the [Authorize] attribute is used.

You can use a tool like Fiddler from Telerik (free) to see the data being transported, but not the content (since its encrypted). Inspecting raw web traffic is invaluable when working with MVC / WebAPI, so I highly recommend it. Here's a link to Fiddler, although other similar tools exist as well.

http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

To answer the second part of your question, the server absolutely checks the contents of the secret key before allowing the request to proceed as authorized.

Answer (score 15):

**Bearer token**

First of all, your Identity Provider or Token Provider which issues the authorization tokens needs to have the same machine key settings as the Web Api application for encryption/decryption:

> <machineKey
>   decryptionKey="B7EFF1C5839A624ED0268917EDE82F408D2ECBFAC817"
>   validation="SHA1"
>   validationKey="C2B8DF31AB9624D8066DFDA1A479542825F3B48865C4E47AF6A026F22D853DEC2B3248DF268599BF89EF78B9E86CA05AC73577E0D5A14C45E0267588850B"
>   />   </system.web>

Because under the hood Bearertoken uses MachineKey encryption.
In other words if you dont have the same settings, your web api won't be able to decrypt the token (validate it).
This is done automatically by:

> Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll

using middleware.

You can use the **Authorize Attribute** on your web api controllers/actions if you want simple authorization with Usernames or roles like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Administrators,Managers",Users ="Mike,Laura")]
```

If you want custom authorization, then you have to implement a custom authorization attribute which will handle the custom authorization in your web api. If the user is not allowed to pass you will return a 401 UnAuthorized Response:

```
actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
actionContext.Response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate","Bearer location='http://localhost:8323/account/login'");
```

**For example:**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public RulesExampleEnum[] Rules { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    .....
// Summary:
//     Calls when a process requests authorization.
//
// Parameters:
//   actionContext:
//     The action context, which encapsulates information for using System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.
public virtual void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext);
public virtual Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
```

and register it in your webApiConfig.cs

```
config.Filters.Add(new CustomAuthorizeAttribute());
```

and apply it on Web Api controller or action:

```
[CustomAuthorize(Id = "AnyId", Rules = new RulesExampleEnum[] { RulesExampleEnum.Rule1, RulesExampleEnum.Rule3 })]
public IEnumerable<object> Get()
{...
```

Comment: This was a lifesaver for me, this is exactly what we are trying to do where an API consumer authenticates with HTTP basic auth (to identify the machine, for access control) and then we want an OAUTH token as well (to identify the user, for permission / identity control).

Answer (score 4):

Once access token is generated, client must include the access token inside Header for each request.

Client may set the access token inside `Authorization` HTTP Header.

On the server side, you should create class to handle the Authorization, which is a derived class from `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute`, something like below :

```
public class AuthorizationHandlerAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    string AccessTokenFromRequest = "";
    if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization != null)
    {
        // get the access token
        AccessTokenFromRequest = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
    }

    string AccessTokenStored = ""; 
    // write some code to get stored access token, probably from database 
    // then assign the value to a variable for later use

    // compare access token
    if (AccessTokenFromRequest != AccessTokenStored)
    {
        // if the token is not valid then return 401 Http Stasus
        // or simply call base method 
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
    }
}
```

Then you use the newly created class and attach it on `controller` or `action` you wished to protect from unauthorized access.

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    [AuthorizationHandler]
    public User Get(int id)
    {
        // only request with valid access token will reach this 
    }
}
```

Comment: In OAuth based authorization you don't store the bearer token on the server-side and use it to compare against the one that is sent via "Authorization" request header). This is an incorrect and unsafe approach.

Answer (score -1):

ChatGPT says-

> When a server receives a JWT token, it must first verify the signature to ensure that the token has not been tampered with. Here are the general steps for how a server validates a JWT token:

Decode the token: The first step is to decode the JWT token. The token consists of three parts, separated by dots. The first part is the header, which contains information about the algorithm used to sign the token. The second part is the payload, which contains the claims (or data) being transmitted. The third part is the signature, which is used to verify the authenticity of the token.

Verify the signature: The server must use the algorithm specified in the header to re-create the signature using the header and payload, along with the secret key that was used to sign the token. If the newly created signature matches the signature in the token, then the server can be confident that the token has not been tampered with and that it was signed by a trusted party.

Verify the claims: After the signature has been verified, the server should verify the claims contained in the payload to ensure that they are valid and match the expected values. For example, the server may check that the user ID in the token matches the user ID in its own database.

Check the token expiration: Finally, the server should check the expiration time of the token to ensure that it has not expired. If the token has expired, the server should reject the token.

If all of the above checks pass, the server can trust that the token is authentic and contains valid information about the user. The server can then use the claims in the token to identify and authorize the user for access to the requested resources or services.